# Calling an external API in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I have one API which needs to be integrated in my existing application developed in c# mvc.

URL – 'SOme url'
RequestMethod -POST

Request Body –

{

"flag":"RECH",

"vrn":"KA01KA05",

"etcCustId":"",

"rechargeTxnid":"KARN0000000000000005",

"rechargeAmt":"200.00"

}

I am calling above API in my code as below

```
       using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
       {

                    var URL='some url';
                    var json = new StringBuilder();
              
                    json.Append("\"flag\": \"" + "RECH" + "\","); 
                    json.Append("\"vrn\": \"KA19\",");
                    json.Append("\"rechargeTxnid\": \"1234\",");
                    json.Append("\"rechargeAmt\": \"200.00\"");       
                    var data = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                 
                    try
                    {
                        var response = await client.PostAsync(URL, data);
                        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                       return result;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                      
                       return "Exception" + e.Message;
                    }
               
            }


        }
```

Am I doing it right?.  Please suggest

Comment: better to create an object of the request and convert it into JSON string before sending

Answer (score 0):

If you install nuget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client you will have access to the System.Net.Http.Formatting assembly which contains many methods to deal with these scenario.

For example you could do:

```
Client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, requestObject);
```

And pass an actual instance of a class... And not worry about JSON serialization etc...

Same is true for getting a JSON response.

This is the recommended way to deal with this scenario.

**NOTE:** You do NOT need "WebClient" as you are NOT using it in your code at all.
And also take into account that HttpClient is meant to be used as a **singleton** so you do not want to instantiate it on every request but rather have a single instance be reused during the lifetime of your program.

Comment: @viveknuna yes it does.....  I use it all the time... I have apps published on Linux using this same code.